# Webform confirmation message is not being saved

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

When I change webform confirmation message it doesn't save in db and shows the last state. The `dpm($form_state)` in webform submit function shows that confirmation text in $form_state['input'] and $form_state['values'] differs. Consequently its dropping inserted values. I try to clear cache in `cache_form` table but its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look into $form_state['input']['submitted']?

Comment: Its not webform submittion, I'm about webform settings page.

Comment: Then, reinstall the module

Comment: Its not helping.